# rsync - transfer only files whose file name starts with today's date

Tags: rsync, transfer

I want to transfer files using `rsync` to a FTP at the end of every day.

My current `rsync` script:

```
rsync -avz /var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3 pbciftp:/home/voicefiles/ftp/`date +%Y.%m.%d`
```

**The issue**
I want rsync to transfer files that have today's date in their file name; a file might for example be called `20130527_agent_number_campaign.mp3`.

So I need rsync to find all files whose file name starts with `20130527` and transfer them.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is probably with find. Something like:

```
find /var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3 -name "*`date +%Y%m%d`*" -print0 | \
rsync -avz --files-from=- --from0 \
/var/spool/asterisk/monitorDONE/MP3 pbciftp:/home/voicefiles/ftp/`date +%Y.%m.%d`
```